# What is the laplacian of $| \nabla u |^2$, where $u$ is harmonic on an open set $\Omega$, subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Show that if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is open, $ u\in C^2(\Omega)$ harmonic, $v=| \nabla{u} |^2$, then:

$$
\Delta v \geq 0 \text{ in } \Omega
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elliptic regularity implies that $u$ has plenty of derivatives, so $\Delta \nabla u$ makes sense.
$$ \Delta (a \cdot b) = b \cdot \Delta a + a \cdot \Delta b + \nabla a : \nabla b, $$
where $ A : B = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}B_{ij} $, (by using summation convention, for example) so
$$ \Delta \lvert \nabla u \rvert^2 = 2(\nabla u) \cdot (\Delta \nabla u) + \lVert \nabla \nabla u \rVert^2 = 2(\nabla u) \cdot \nabla (\Delta u) + \lVert \nabla \nabla u \rVert^2, $$
where $\lVert A \rVert^2 = \sum_{i,j} \lvert A_{ij} \rvert^2 $. If $u$ is harmonic, the first term is zero. The second term is nonnegative, since it is a sum of squares.